# What Membership Payment Date should appear in membership reports?

Tags: civimember, civireport, contributions

I'm wondering if the following is expected behavior or a bug. When running a detailed Membership Report and selecting Date Received as one of the columns, I would expect to see the most recent payment date for the membership. However, instead it shows the first payment date, however long ago that might have been.

While I can sort-of fix that by setting the filter to show only payments received in the last 12 months, that filters out any members who don't have a payment date (such as comp members), and if a member has paid twice within the past 12 months, it shows the first rather than second payment during that time.

I'm running Civi 4.7.14 on Joomla 3.6.5

Comment: Looks like a bug. I tried sorting on the receive date and it didn't change anything, so I'd guess it's just pulling in the first one it finds.